# What skill enhances the use of spears?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

Spears are labeled as "Reach Weapon" in the game when you look at the Tooltip, however, there seems to be no skill that enhances them:

[image: Skills]
[image: Spear]

Which skill affects that weapon?

Comment: There might just not be one, in order to keep you from using spears all game.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reach weapons don't have a seperate skill, but they have a property that makes them somewhat usefull never the less:
They can be used from the back row.

Comment: +1 for "somewhat useful".  This is less useful on a Rogue character as you can skill up the Assassination skill and gain an all-melee-weapon reach attack (12 points in).  This lets daggers become much more useful, as you probably wouldn't want to put a rogue on the front row.  You probably want tanks there instead.

Comment: See: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62244/how-can-i-get-my-party-member-in-range